# How can i Post image at instagram using API or Direct Image link

Tags: instagram

How do I share a link and photo with Instagram using PHP? I can't find anything for "share photo with instagram".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://instagram.com/developer/endpoints/media/

"At this time, uploading via the API is not possible"

Comment: It's interesting that this quote was removed from the page found via that link. However there's still no POST method listed for Media, so I figure it's still the case. :thinking_face: